# How to compare files in soapui through groovy script?

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I have been able to successfully save the response into and external file - `response.json`
Now I need to write a groovy script to compare `response.json` with `baseline.json`.

My query revolves around how could I parse `baseline.json` into a variable, say

```
def File1 = baseline.json
```

So that later I could compare the two files through groovy.
This is what I am doing, however I am unable to store external file to a variable,

My groovy script as:

```
def a = context.expand('${#TestSuite#BaseLineFolder}') + "\\file1.json" //log.info a 
def slurper = new JsonSlurper() 
def File1 = slurper.parseText (a)
```

Comment: `JsonSlurper` can be used for parsing `JSON` files.

Comment: Thanks Opal
This is what I am doing however  I am unable to store external file to a variable, My groovy script as:
def a = context.expand('${#TestSuite#BaseLineFolder}') + "\\file1.json"
//log.info a

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def File1 = slurper.parseText (a)

Answer (score 1):

I helped a friend solve the same problem a few days ago. She has a json response saved in an external file and wanted to compare that to the json response in soapUI. My solution to her was..

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def filePath = "c:/storage/json/localJson.json" //change this to your json file
def jsonResp = context.expand('${CitiesJSON - Request 1#Response}') //CitiesJSON - Request 1 is the name of my test request

assert jsonResp.size() > 0, "No Json response received"

//jParser and jFParser are java.util.HashMaps
def jParser = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonResp)
def jFParser = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new File(filePath).text)

//verify the size
assert jParser.size() == jFParser.size(), "The two jsons do not have same number of values"

int i = 0

//loop through the json
jParser.each{
    assert it.value.size() == jFParser[it.key].size(), "Json not of same size"

    for(i = 0; i<it.value.size();i++) {
        it.value[i].each{ k, v ->
            log.info "jParser = ${k}:${v}"
            log.info "jFParser = ${k}:"+jFParser[it.key][k][i]
            def jpVal = v
            def jfpVal = jFParser[it.key][k][i]
            assert jpVal == jfpVal, "value not same"
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek however I am getting error as -

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.size() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), with(groovy.lang.Closure), times(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;) error at line: 18

when I run this code.. any clue? I am new to groovy

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way we could compare whether the two json files are identical or not. It also determine at which node the value differs.

```
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def filePath = "c:/storage/json/localJson.json" //change this to your json file
def jsonResp = context.expand('${CitiesJSON - Request 1#Response}') //CitiesJSON - Request 1 is the name of my test request

def outputResp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonResp)
def baselineResp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new File(filePath).text)

baselineResp.each{

    if (!(it.value == outputResp[it.key]))
    {
        log.info ("File Mismatch at : " + it.key)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

call JSON compare method with parameters as given below,

```
 object.compareJSONResponse(stepRes,filePath,expRes);
```